# Electrical pole wires dividing

Tags: power-supply

I would like to ask you very lay question. I know that there are 3 phases wires on this electrical pole on this picture. But where is neutral wire? I want to have more clear in this question.

Thank you

[image]

EDIT:

I thought until now that neutral wire is needed as output always. And so wires which are going from electric power generator for example from water power plant can be just phases, no need neutral wire?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the load (on each phase) is balanced the current in the neutral wire is zero hence can be omitted. In reality there is always some imbalance, this is typically only an issue at the delivery end due to load imbalance.

Comment: that poor generator jammed with its rotor way off center :)

Comment: Your diagram is of a wye (Y) generator.  Most high-power units are delta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A neutral wire is not required to transmit 3-phase power. It is not required for distribution and usage either in many situations. It is only used in situations where it is desirable to use line-to-neutral connection for single-phase loads at a lower voltage than the line-to-line connection.

Neutrals are generally formed where required using a transformer. They are the exception rather than the rule. A neutral is not made available at the generator except where a portable generator is designed for loads to be connected directly.

Answer (score 12):

One of the advantages of three-phase power is that the cost of the transmission line is optimised by elimination of the neutral conductor. Neutral is added in at the step-down transformer.

[image]

*Figure 1. Delta-star (wye) three-phase transformer. The star point can be neutralised by connection to ground.*

Comment: you beat me for 52 seconds.

Comment: Yes, it's tough in here!

Comment: So in star variant is ine more cable needed, yes?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't need to have a neutral. The neutral becomes the earth.

[image]

The star point of the transformer secondary is grounded, then you get PEN wire, which is then divided into PE and N.

Comment: It might be informative to add what PEN stands for.

Comment: I have one maybe easy question for you. How is current flowing back in delta variant? In star variant with neutral wire is clear, all current is going trough neutral wire back.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't one.

I don't know what country that picture was taken in, but it looks very similar to what you see in rural parts of the UK. If it was in the UK then the lines would most likely be 11KV.

A three phase system does not strictly have to have a Neutral. Systems can either use a delta connection for loads, or if they do use a star connection they can rely on the ground to carry imbalance currents.

At least in the UK overhead medium voltage wiring* typically does not have a neutral or ground wire. I believe the norm is for the supply to use a star connection to provide the system with some reference to ground while the loads (stepdown transformers) are delta connected so they don't cause any imbalance currents.

On the other hand the "low voltage" wiring used to deliver power to homes and businesses typically does have a Neutral. I believe systems with a Neutral are typically used for final distribution because they give two different voltages allowing much of the benefits of the higher voltage for distribution while providing the lower voltages for utilization.

* 1KV or so to 38KV or so (definitions vary) but most commonly in the UK either 6.6KV, 11KV or 33KV.

** less than 1KV, but most commonly in the UK 230/400V three phase or occasionally 230/460V split phase.